# neoload release history and compatibility for web, controller, and load generator

Tags: neoload

I want to know the compatibility for neoload releases mainly because we're using 2.8.0.  That is the version I see when I log into Neoload web, so I presume it must be neoload web 2.8.0.

I came across this article, but 2.8.0 isn't even listed.  I'm not sure if 2.8.0 is the version of neoload web and if so, what controller / load generator versions it would be compatible with.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeoLoad

Secondly, I would like to provision load generators and controllers easily and found these: https://hub.docker.com/r/neotys/neoload-loadgenerator
https://hub.docker.com/r/neotys/neoload-controller

Those are for the latest and greatest.  I am wondering if that would work, or not.

I ran the load generator and controller in a docker container locally pointed at our neoload web api and it seems to connect and run, but I have no idea if that is directly supported or not.  I cannot seem to find any supporting documentation.

EDIT #1:
I have Neoload Web 2.8.0, would Neoload Controller 2023.2 and Neoload Load Generator 2023.2 work with that version of web?

Comment: "the compatibility for neoload releases" - compatibility to which other tools?

Comment: I updated the question with the versions I was trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we are using neoload 8.1.1 and that is what we have a license.  If I try to run a newer version, it will fail to get a license.  It would be helpful to know that the license did not support a newer version.